# Getting Model View Projection Matrix without GLM in C++

Tags: c++, math, graphics, opengl-es-2.0

I have this code that uses a library `GLM`, that sets a variable `projMatrix` with the correct MVP matrix, later i give this to a Shader function as a uniform and it works that way.

```
   void setMVP(GLfloat r, GLfloat l, GLfloat t, GLfloat b, GLfloat n, GLfloat f){
       glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
       glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
                                     glm::vec3(l, b, n),
                                     glm::vec3(l, b, f),
                                     glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
       glm::mat4 proj =  glm::ortho(l, r, b, t, n, f);
       projMatrix = proj * view * model;
   }
```

I want to now remove the `glm` library because i only needed it for this small task, so i want to calculate the matrix myself to avoid having an entire library for one task.

I'm using an online matrix calculator to give me the result in terms of variables so i need to only assign the resultant values to array indexes, i'm using that but it doesnt seem to be working this way. ([Link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-multiply-calculator/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Br-l%7D%260%260%26-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(r%2Bl%5Cright)%7D%7B%5Cleft(r-l%5Cright)%7D%5C%5C%200%26%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Bt-b%7D%260%26-%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(t%2Bb%5Cright)%7D%7B%5Cleft(t-b%5Cright)%7D%5C%5C%200%260%26%5Cfrac%7B-2%7D%7Bf-n%7D%26-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(f%2Bn%5Cright)%7D%7B%5Cleft(f-n%5Cright)%7D%5C%5C%200%260%260%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Ccdot%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Dl%26b%26n%260%5C%5C%20l%26b%26f%260%5C%5C%200%261%260%260%5C%5C%200%260%260%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D)) The link opens up the exact multiplication that i'm doing. But when i use the values they do not work. I must be missing something.

Here is my breakdown.

1) The model matrix is identity so it doesnt matter if i multiply it or not.

2) For Orthographic projection i'm using the following

[image: img] (l=left, r=right, t=top, b=bottom, n=near, f=far)

3) For the camera placement, i had set it with the glm library was in place and it was working alright, so i think i dont need to modify it.

Comment: Just keep the library and don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The project i'm using this in is already pretty heavy or rather the previous build was, it would increase the performance if i remove the redundant code. Keeping only c++ source code is one of the goal at the moment.

Comment: Plus i know it can be done, but i'm just missing something and i need help in that.

Comment: It's a pretty lightweight library, therefore I don't see the reason. It will not increase performance, it's unlikely you will implement it more efficient than glm does. It is C++ code, so that sentence makes no sense. But if you really want to do it, maybe show us the code you have already tried and didn't work? Or you can simply just copy paste the implementation of `glm::lookAt`, `glm::ortho`...